# How to setup apache reverse proxy for particular domain

Tags: apache, proxy, virtualhost, reverse-proxy, mod-proxy

I have some app installed on `appname.com` and I am using `apache` `proxy` server. Both are on different servers.

When user tries to access website `appname.com` I want to do `Basic Authentication` using proxy and if he completes authentication I want to send his username in headers to `appname.com` which is on different server than `proxy`

I have done similar thing for `myproxy.com/appname` location with below working solution.

```
ProxyPass /appname http://appname.com
ProxyPassReverse /wordpress http://appname.com

<Location /appname>
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Restricted Files"
    # (Following line optional)
    AuthBasicProvider file
    AuthUserFile /home/tomcat/apache/.htpasswd
    Require valid-user

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule .* - [E=RU:%{REMOTE_USER}]
    RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-User %{REMOTE_USER}s
</Location>
```

I want same solution for domain `appname.com` instead of location `/appname`. I tries with `VirtualHost` but not able to do it as appname.com is on different server than proxy.

Any hint for that? Thanks.